# Getting Error : Invalid or incorrect number of columns in the THEAD; expected 1465, but found 1000 columns

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using Jquery Tablesorter.
It uses zebra, sorter, sticky header widgets.

```
$('#DM993982_tbl').tablesorter({
  widthFixed : true,
  widgets: ['zebra', 'staticRow', 'stickyHeaders'],
  widgetOptions: {
    stickyHeaders_attachTo: '#DM993982_tbl_tw'
  }, 
  headers: {}
});
```

When i use more than 1000 columns i get the error in the console and the browser gets stuck.

> Invalid or incorrect number of columns in the THEAD; expected 1465, but found 1000 columns

Please help me find a solution.
Thanks

This is the error stack

```
jquery.tablesorter.min.js:1 Invalid or incorrect number of columns in the 
THEAD; expected 1465, but found 1000 columns
checkColumnCount @ jquery.tablesorter.min.js:1
computeColumnIndex @ jquery.tablesorter.min.js:1
buildHeaders @ jquery.tablesorter.min.js:1
setup @ jquery.tablesorter.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ jquery.tablesorter.min.js:1
each @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
each @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
A.fn.tablesorter @ jquery.tablesorter.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ VM193:60
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ VM193:60
_621 @ dojo.js:15
_61d @ dojo.js:15
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:15
_9 @ dojo.js:15
req.signal @ dojo.js:15
_38 @ dojo.js:15
_16 @ dojo.js:15
req @ dojo.js:15
(anonymous) @ VM193:1
d.eval @ VM45:3
(anonymous) @ xhr.js?1568189044706:92
_4ec @ dojo.js:15
_4e6 @ dojo.js:15
resolve @ dojo.js:15
_4f2 @ dojo.js:15
_4ec @ dojo.js:15
_4e6 @ dojo.js:15
resolve @ dojo.js:15
_4f2 @ dojo.js:15
_4ec @ dojo.js:15
_4e6 @ dojo.js:15
resolve @ dojo.js:15
_4f2 @ dojo.js:15
_4ec @ dojo.js:15
_4e6 @ dojo.js:15
resolve @ dojo.js:15
_40b @ dojo.js:15
_417 @ dojo.js:15
load (async)
_411 @ dojo.js:15
xhr @ dojo.js:15
_48e.<computed> @ dojo.js:15
LoadAppPostForm @ xhr.js?1568189044706:79
_DM505878frm_btnSubmit1_click @ VM131:242
DM505878frm_btnSubmit1_click @ VM131:244
(anonymous) @ VM131:245
_60c @ dojo.js:15
_onClick @ _ButtonMixin.js?1568189044706:16
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:15
__onClick @ _ButtonMixin.js?1568189044706:7
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:15
on.emit @ dojo.js:15
(anonymous) @ touch.js?1568189044706:96
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ touch.js?1568189044706:95
```

Comment: It sounds like the HTML isn't valid.

Comment: If i generate less than 1000 columns it works properly. Only when it crosses 1000 columns i get this error. May there is some limit in Tablesorter ?

Comment: No limit. What browser are you using? Do you see the same issue in other browsers?

Comment: I have given the error stack in my question. I use chrome. In firefox the page gets stuck and aks to wait or stop. I have to click stop. I get no error in the console of firefox.

Comment: Tablesorter only reports the column count inconsistency, it doesn't stop the code. Try removing all the widgets and see if it works. I suspect the static row & sticky header widgets might have some problems since the column count is off.

Comment: Tried removing all the widgets and options. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Please update [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/jo3hqk0v/) to duplicate the problem.

Comment: I have updated the JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xkujb4p0/4/ . I have added more than 1000 columns and 6 rows. The error shows up in the console. However the table is loading correctly. Encouraged by this I changed my page to just 4 rows and it loaded in 3 minutes even though the error still showed up in the console.To show 35 rows it takes about 6 minutes. Why does it take up so much time.

Comment: Hmm, so weird. When I scroll all the way to the right, the colspan stops at 1000. When I access the `colSpan` property of that `th`, it reports 1000. Maybe there is a limit I'm not seeing imposed by browsers?